# RDCOMClient on linux docker

Tags: r, docker, rdcomclient

We are trying to run R scripts with the RDCOMClient lib on AWS Dockers, but we are getting some erros. We are installing the package with the following command:

```
devtools::install_github("omegahat/RDCOMClient")
```

And it gives us this error:

```
RCOMObject.h:23:21: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
```

We are using R version 3.3.1 with linux docker images.

Is there any way to make this work? Is there some other lib we can use?

Comment: What OS are you attempting to run this docker? RDCOMClient interfaces with Windows' COM (Command Object Model). It cannot work in other OS's or in the cloud (unless on a Windows environment).

Comment: tks for the reply, that solves what I need